# Сервера для сайтов 2p2 с возможностью заработка для юзеров

Tags: веб-сервер, хостинг, p2p

Какая архитектура должна быть у проекта в котором сайт, сервер распределен по компьютерам участников. Каждый участник размещает у себя информацию для раздачи информации, доступа к сайту для других пользователей в интернете. Пользователи которые размещают свои сайты на таких компьютерах платят пользователям которые хранят у них сайты.

Comment: Изучите подробно работу DNS и что такое реальные IP адреса и поймете, что идея обречена на провал ввиду нестабильности такой схемы работы. А по поводу распределения информации по компьютерам пользователей изучайте протоколы работы torrent

Comment: Ну либо вам потребуется кроме сети хранения еще и сеть раздачи на подобии Tor. Но тогда надо будет еще продумать вопрос вознаграждения для участников сети раздачи

Comment: И да, еще с коммерческой составляющей проблемы явно будут. Стабильность хостинга за 300р/мес окажется значительно выше чем такой сети